# Specified argument was our of the range of valid values

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project that I was thrown into. I'm not a software developer by any stretch. The problem I'm having is an error:

[image: error message]

Using message boxes I was able to trace down the function that is causing this error to occur. Here is the code that leads to this error:

```cs
try
{
    String type = "I";
    String fullMessage = Convert.ToChar(1) + type + Convert.ToChar(2) + Convert.ToChar(3) + Convert.ToChar(13);
    NetworkStream serverStream = client.GetStream();
    byte[] outStream = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fullMessage);
    serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
    serverStream.Flush(); ;
    
    byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
    await serverStream.ReadAsync(inStream, 0, (int)client.ReceiveBufferSize);
    string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
    if (returndata.Length == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("isError = true in try");
        isError = true;
        connected = false;
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    isError = true;
    connected = false;
}
```

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The error seems to be saying you are calling a method named `BeginRead()` and one of the arguments contained a value that is out of the valid range. Looking at your code, it doesn't appear you included the code that calls this method so I can only guess at one what you're doing. If you run the program in debug mode, it should stop and take you exactly to the line causing the error. Next time, show *that* code.

Comment: @JonathanWood I searched the entire project for BeginRead() and I didn't find anything. I'm reasonably certain that there is no BeginRead method in here. I didn't write this code I was just tasked with fixing so I'm not exactly sure of how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Again, if you run the program in debug mode it should take you to the exact line that is causing the error. Show us which line that is. You don't seem to be helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the stacktrace that `ReadAsync` is part of it a few methods up in the chain. Checking the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.readasync?view=net-6.0#system-net-sockets-networkstream-readasync(system-byte()-system-int32-system-int32-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) we can see the parameters:

> buffer Byte[]
>
> The buffer to write the data into.

You have just created the buffer, so this should be fine.

> offset  Int32
>
> The location in buffer to begin storing the data to.

This is zero, i.e. begin writing at the start of the buffer, a perfectly reasonable value.

> count  Int32
>
> The number of bytes to read from the NetworkStream.

This has the value `client.ReceiveBufferSize`, and i would guess that this needs to be smaller than the length of the buffer. But there is no way to tell from the example if this is actually the case.

This can further be confirmed by checking the documentation for [BeginRead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginread?view=net-6.0):

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException
>
> The offset parameter is less than 0.
>
> -or-
>
> The offset parameter is greater than the length of the buffer parameter.
>
> -or-
>
> The size is less than 0.
>
> -or-
>
> **The size is greater than the length of buffer minus the value of the offset parameter.**

There seem to be a bug in the documentation in that *size* should probably be *count*